# Is having all wireless devices (both visitors and home users) use a guest wireless SSID a bad idea?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, internet-security

I'm reluctant to have any wireless devices with visibility into my home LAN systems (PCs / home servers). So I was thinking of having all wireless devices use the guest SSID. Is this a bad idea? I don't need wireless devices to communicate with other systems on the LAN. They just need internet access.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on your Router Or AP hardware.

For example if it was possible to setup your ACCESS POINT on a different subnet. Example: 192.168.2.1 and your network is at 192.168.1.x. Then you'd be golden and you could setup all of your wireless clients on guest or 2G/5G.

If you setup your guest in a way, where they don't have many restrictions (for example bandwidth restrictions). Then I don't see why that would be a problem.

You have to remember, not all Routers and/or access points are the same. They all have different default config values or restrictions for guest wireless networks, IF they have a guest network at all.

Lastly, I know you're asking this due to a high level of paranoia (which is ok). But if nothing on your Hard Line computers/devices are ever sharing anything to the network, I don't see how they could access anything that's on a hard line.